# Como eliminar el mensaje de error que sale dentro del input - php

Tags: php

Hola a todos tengo un pequeño inconveniente con el input, me sale un mensaje de error dentro del input, he estado buscando como resolver pero no he obtenido resultados.

les adjunto una imagen del error que me muestra.
[image: error]

Aquí les adjunto el codigo.

```
  <?php
 include 'conexion.php';
  ?>

 <form action="buscador.php" method="get">
 <input type="text" name="palabra" placeholder="buscar aqui.." value="<?php  echo ($_GET["palabra"]); ?>"  />
  <input type="submit" name="buscador" value="Buscar" id="buscar" />

 <style type="text/css">
   #buscar{
    display: none;
         }
</style>

</form>
<?php 

if(isset($_GET['buscador'])){

$buscar = $_GET['palabra'];

if (empty($buscar)){
echo "No se ha ingresado ninguna palabra";
}
else
{

$sql = "SELECT * FROM registro WHERE nombre LIKE '%$buscar%'";
$result = $conexion->query($sql);

$total = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

echo "Resultados para: $buscar";
?>
<br>
<?php
echo "Total de resultados: $total";

do {
 ?>
<br>
<br>
 <a href="<?php echo $row['link'] ?>">(nombre: <?php echo $row['nombre']; ?>)
 </a>

<?php
}
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result));
}
else
{
echo "No se encontraron resultados para: $buscar";
}
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que al entrar a la página aún no mandas ningun dato por `GET` y ahi te marca el error. Lo que deberias hacer es validar si se esta enviando la variable con la función [isset](http://php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php) y si se mando hacer el `echo`, quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
<input type="text" name="palabra" placeholder="buscar aqui.." value="<?php if (isset($_GET["palabra"])) {  echo $_GET["palabra"]; }?>"  />
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, tienes razón.

Comment: Para eso es la comunidad!! Si te sirvio la respuesta marcala como aceptada.. Saludos

Comment: listo ya esta, pero ahora tengo otra duda, al hacer una consulta me aparece el numero 1 en el input.

Comment: Pero en que momento te aparece el 1 al ingresar a la web o al darle buscar? Deberias de abrir una nueva pregunta para tu duda

Comment: Listo abriré una nueva pregunta. Gracias.